# NAR LaTeX template paperwide table

Tags: tables, templates

I am trying to create a paperwide table using the Nucleic Acid Research LaTeX template. After many attempts I was unable to create such wide table.

Can someone help out in this?

Here is the template:
http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/nar/for_authors/msprep_submission.html

This is the reference code for one column table:

```
\begin{table}[b]
\tableparts{%
\caption{This is a table caption}
\label{table:01}%
}{%
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
Col. head 1 & Col. head 2 & Col. head 3 & Col. head 4 & Col. head 5
\\
& (\%) & (s$^{-1}$) & (\%) & (s$^{-1}$)
\\
\colrule
Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & -- & --
\\
Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2
\\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}%
}
{This is a table footnote}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by “paper wide”? Are you perhaps meaning as wide as the column?

Comment: Hi, I mean two column wide table, like in this paper:
doi: 10.1093/nar/gkw750 (Table 1.)

Comment: You'll have very large white spaces if you want to typeset on full text width a five column table.

Comment: I will add more data into the table, around 10 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the sample file distributed with the class and changed the table environment in your code like

```
\begin{table*}
\tableparts{%
\caption{This is a table caption}
\label{table:01}%
}{%
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllll@{}}
\toprule
Col. head 1 & Col. head 2 & Col. head 3 & Col. head 4 & Col. head 5
\\
& (\%) & (s$^{-1}$) & (\%) & (s$^{-1}$)
\\
\colrule
Row 1 & Row 1 & Row 1 & -- & --
\\
Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2 & Row 2
\\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}%
}
{This is a table footnote}
\end{table*}
```

Note `table*`, `\textwidth` instead of `\columnwidth` and `\extracolsep`. The resulting table is at the top of the picture.

[image]